# Is there any way to disable magnifier's cursor in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, drilldown, magnify

*Crystal Reports* shows *magnifier* cursor in group fields, which hide the header section. So I don't want to use this *magnifier*. So how can I disable this *magnifier* cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: it can't be done.

If you mark the Details section as 'Suppress (No Drill-Down)', the magnifying glass will still be displayed.  Moreover, double-click a group-title or summary field will still generate a drill-down page, but the Details section will be suppressed (no visible).

Most users find the ability to see ('drill down') the the details as a valuable feature.  You should design your report with that in mind.